# error in running the server for DBpedia Lookup in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, dbpedia

I want to run a local mirror of the webservice for DBlookup,in which i hv done with three steps i.e Clone and build the DBpedia extraction framework , Clone and build DBpedia Lookup and Download and configure the index but not able to perform fourth step "Run the server" to check this step you can go through this url:https://github.com/dbpedia/lookup.

when i try for cmd : ./run Server dbpedia-lookup-index-3.8

I got the error :  Error resolving version for 'net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin': Plugin requires Maven version 3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This occurs because dbpedia-lookup-index require maven 3.0 version but current version it found is not 3.0.So follow the following steps to install maven 3

1. sudo apt-get remove maven2
2. sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/natecarlson/maven3/ubuntu precise main"
3. sudo apt-get update
4. sudo apt-get install maven3
5. sudo ln -s /usr/share/maven3/bin/mvn /usr/bin/mvn
6. Remove PPA from sources.list  remove this link http://ppa.launched.net/netcarlson/maven3/ubuntuprecise main

And again follow the same procedure for step1 to step 5.You can the access the local dbpedia at local host